# Stuck with reject and update loop Google play console

Tags: google-play, publishing, google-developers-console

My app keeps getting rejected regarding a policy violation, which on further enquiry seems to be because I used "Amazon" in my app description to denote the affiliate I added in the application.

Soon after knowing this, I changed my app description on the Google Play Console. However, the app's listing wasn't updated. Usually, the store listing is updated when you make a new release.

So I'm now stuck in a loop where they reject my release because of the app's description and I need to release to update my the app's description. I am pretty much stuck with this for almost a month now.

The email in question:

> **Reason for rejection**
>
> *Your app has been rejected and wasn't published due to a policy violation. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still available on Google Play.*
>
> **Support reply**
>
> *Step 1: Fix the policy violation with your app*
>
> During review, we found that your app appears to use popular brands, characters, and other assets associated with patterns of harmful behavior or high risk of abuse and determined your app to have a high risk profile.
>
> For example, your app’s description currently contains the use of popular brands.

[Play Store link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wishem&hl=en)

Comment: Are you able to fix this issue? I am facing the same for one of my app.

Comment: @AbdulRauf I raised a ticket and explained them. so gave a clear direct problem with my store listing. It seems i use "google" term in my app description. so no brand names in app description. If you dont know whats the exact problem, raise a ticket and they will give a more direct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raised a ticket to elaborate the privacy policy issue and the support gave a more direct reason for the rejection of app update. In my case it's using brand names on app description. I used "Google contacts" in my app description, where including the word Google is a violation according to play policies.

Comment: Received the same reject today, reading OP, I removed this from the app's description (and filled an appeal) :Supports network shares using Samba, FTP/S, WebDAV, G-Drive and Dropbox. Hard to believe this is considered potentially harmful or high risk of abuse.

Comment: How did you raise a ticket and how long did they take to respond ?